# LESS Mixin Template?

Tags: less

I'm just curious if anyone knows of any templates out there for LESS with mixins to get you started with useful mixins (kind of like snippets in Sublime Text).  I've already created a lot of mixins like the ones [here](http://css3please.com/), so creating my own that are identical might be a waste of time if they're already out there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied some from http://designshack.net/articles/css/10-less-css-examples-you-should-steal-for-your-projects/ into my own project.

This seems to have a file to download: http://lesselements.com/ (i have not used this so far)